# MongoDB schema structure and queries

Tags: mongodb

I've just dived into mongoDB development. Using the shell, I'm able to store the following into a collection called vrm:

```
w = {
  westpalm :{
    users : [
      {pkanane : {names : {lastName : "Anane", otherNames : "Papa Kwame"}}, contacts : {}, authorization : {}},
      {csquire : {}},
      {oman : {}}
    ],
    customers : [], 
    vehicles : [], 
    settings : []

  }  
}

a = {
  wuduwudu :{
    users : [
      {pkanane : {names : {lastName : "Anane", otherNames : "Papa Kwame"}}, contacts : {}, authorization : {}},
      {zkenpachi : {}}
    ],
    customers : [], 
    vehicles : [], 
    settings : []

  }  
}
```

I then save as follows db.vrm.save(a) and db.vrm.save(w)

Q1. What I'm trying to model is **2** companies **wuduwudu** and **westpalm**, each company has **users**, **customers**, **vehicles** etc. Each user has a **name** -made up of **lastName** and **otherNames**, **contacts** etc. Is this a good way to model the data requirements?

Q2. How can I retrieve the **otherNames** of the user **pkanane**

Thanks

Comment: JohnnyHK thanks for the tip..forgot the Social aspect of Stack Overflow.. don't know why i was down-voted by sum1 tho..I felt I would get the best answer here..

Comment: It wasn't me, but you were probably downvoted because Q1 is an opinion question and Q2 doesn't show any evidence regarding what you've tried so far that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll address your second question first, in the context of your original schema. Using the username as the index is going to make querying much more difficult, as you'll have a variable field name to work with. Likewise, indexing such fields within the user object will not scale, as each distinct field path would require its own index. That said, it is possible with an inefficient query:

```
db.companies.drop()
db.companies.insert({
    _id: "wuduwudu",
    users: [
        { pkanane: { fullName: "Papa Kwame" } }
    ]
});
db.companies.find({ "users.pkanane": { $exists: true }}, { "users.pkanane.fullName": 1 });
{ "_id" : "wuduwudu", "users" : [ { "pkanane" : { "fullName" : "Papa Kwame" } } ] }
```

An improvement would be to make `users` an array of embedded user objects. With this schema, you could take advantage of [multikey indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) on the `users.username` field and Mongo would index all usernames in the array for each document.

```
db.companies.drop()
db.companies.insert({
    _id: "westpalm",
    users: [
        { username: "pkanane", fullName: "Papa Kwame" }
    ]
});
db.companies.find({ "users.username": "pkanane" }, { "users.pkanane.fullName": 1 });
{ "_id" : "wuduwudu", "users" : [ { "pkanane" : { "fullName" : "Papa Kwame" } } ] });
```

---

For rethinking your schema, I'd start by looking at the company and user object structures. As I mentioned above, dynamic field names are not going to work well with indexing. I'd advise against using the company name as as the only top-level key in your document. You can use it for an `_id`, as I did in the examples above, or rely on MongoDB to generate ObjectId's and store the company name in its own field alongside the `users`, `customers`, etc.

Generally, users are first-class objects in most applications. If you using and editing them outside of the context of a company, I'd consider storing them in their own collections and instead keeping an array of user ID's in your company document. Also, in your own example, you were duplicating "pkanane" between both companies. That's another smell that you may be better off referencing a user document in its own collection. Customers, vehicles and settings may not be first-class objects in your application, so it might be more appropriate to embed them. The [Schema Design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-SummaryofBestPractices) entry in the MongoDB documentation is a good starting point (I've linked to the list of best practices).

Another challenge with embedded documents may be the requirement that your application allow a single embedded document to be edited on its own. This is typical for schemas that embed an address book in a user document and provide an "Edit Your Address" form. Using the array position of the object, which can change, is not reliable as having an immutable field on the object. Using the schema in my second code example above, we could use `username` if it's immutable. Alternatively, we could store a unique ObjectId on each embedded document and reference that.

On that last note, you may end up moving users to their own collection, but the advice would be valid for whatever you leave embedded on the company.

Comment: thanks a lot man..Interesting..Id post what i finally settle on..cheers